# Is there a non-integer in the dimension spectrum for the Heisenberg group?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, geometric-group-theory, noncommutative-geometry, spectral-triples

Let $\Gamma = \langle a,b,c \ | \  c=aba^{-1}b^{-1}, \ ac=ca, \ bc = cb \rangle$ be the discrete Heisenberg group.
Let $\ell: \Gamma \to \mathbb{N} $ be the word length on $\Gamma$.   This group has a polynomial growth rate of order $4$.
Let $H$ be the separable Hilbert space $l^2(\Gamma)$. Let $A$ be the ${\rm C}^{\star}$-algebra ${\rm C}^{\star}_r(\Gamma)$.
Let $D$ be the (unbounded) Dirac  operator  on $H$, defined as an extension of the map $ \gamma \mapsto \ell(\gamma)\gamma$.

*Question:* Is there a non-integer in the [dimension spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_triple#Definition) of the [spectral triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_triple) $(A,H,D)$?

*Remark*: The intuitive reason why we expect the existence of a non-integer in this dimension spectrum, is that the Heisenberg group admits $3$ generators, but a polynomial growth rate of order $4$, so *something* should happen strictly between $3$ and $4$. Moreover, non-integers appear in some results about some generalized Heisenberg groups (see [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs002220050090) of Michael Stoll).